# How can I relate PDFs and Files using an Element Select field in my custom plugin?

Tags: templating, plugin-development, elementtype

I would like to create an elementSelect form field in my plugin, and can't find an example or description. Can someone help?

Comment: Do you already have a custom Element for your plugin set up and working?

Comment: i have in my plugin folder templates/_fieldtypes/customers.html.

insert file:

{{ checkboxSelect({
    name: name,
    options: options,
    values: values,
}) }}

Comment: @florian Can you please update your question with more info? What’s the context here, and what “elementSelect” are you referring to? What have you already tried?

Comment: i want select some pdfs and files in my plugin.

The module looks like this:
http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for something like the example posted here which goes into detail on several items necessary to create a working Asset Relations Field in a custom plugin:
https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/456/115